# Accidentally created a feature branch and have been working off of it in Git for months, how do I bring it back into master without losing changes?

Tags: git

I created a feature branch and more or less forgot I had for a few months until I realized all the work was done out of that branch while "master" basically sat doing nothing.

I tried to merge the feature branch back into master, but it put all the commits into one which is super confusing and makes seeing changes over time in the files a pain.

How do I do this properly so that effectively I can pretend I just stayed in master all these months?

(What confuses me more is my git GUI client shows the history graph as just a straight vertical graph where I would think it should show master as being stuck behind and this feature branch going way ahead. Can anyone explain that?)

Comment: You *should* be working on feature branches, and should never be working on `master` directly. However, feature branches should branch off of `develop`, rather than `master`. It sounds like you're looking for a `git squash`, but I'd conjecture that leaving the history there will allow you to work out the various points at which code was added -- you can never have a git log that's *too* extensive.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Sorry so what are you suggesting exactly? git squash won't do? What would you normally do here then if I'm doing things right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight vertical graph indicates `feature` is a number of commits ahead of `master`. They are not diverged. If diverged, `feature` has one or more commits which are not on `master` and at the same time `master` has one or more commits which are not on `feature`. In the current situation, all the commits on `master` are also reachable from `feature`, and `feature` has some commits which are not on `master` yet.

By `it put all the commits into one`, it means a squash merge takes place. You didn't mention which GUI tool, but it should have an item which says something like `squash` on the merge menu. If it's checked, the commits are converted to a single commit which contains all the changes. If you don't want such merge strategy, uncheck it.

As `feature` is ahead of `master`, a fast-forward merge will happen by default. No merge commit will be created. If you want a merge commit, check the item which says something like `no fast forward`.

In the command line, you can try

```
git checkout master

# fast forward merge
git merge feature

# no fast forward merge
git merge feature --no-ff

# squash merge
git merge feature --squash && git commit
```

Comment: Oh the lack of a merge commit is what I wanted, thank you